# Root div still covering half of the page, even the height sets to zero

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using react, and suddenly I encounter weird behavior happened in my application. Half of it is covered by the div#root (from top to half) and it has specified height of 1841px and I can't figure out where does it came from. I go right away modifying it's height by 0px. Still, another even more weird happened again that this root still covering having a new height specified to 0.

I spent hours investigating. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Remove DOM elements a few at a time until the problem goes away, then add them back one at a time to figure out where the problem is coming from.

Comment: The root div in React is where all of the application should be rendered. What is your use case for wanting to hide this div? Maybe there is a better solution.